# Rename [asp.net-identity-3] to [asp-net-core-identity]

Tags: discussion, support, retag-request

Today I noticed that the [asp.net-identity-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-identity-3) tag still carries over it's old name.

As [announced on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/144), ASP.NET 5 and Entity Framework 7 is in the process of being renamed to ASP.NET Core 1.0 and Entity Framework Core 1.0. As a result of this, ASP.NET Identity 3.0 also gots renamed to ASP.NET Core Identity 1.0.

So renaming the tag to [asp.net-core-identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-identity) will make sense, it already happened with [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core).

Comment: No comments on this one? asp-net-identity-3 is still misleading with the recent version reset of all ASP.NET Core libraries

Comment: that new tag now already exists, should it be a synonym now?